I'm parsing a xml file with libxml2, no problem with search an element. But return xmlNodePtr (cur_node) to it's caller is it NULL
I struggle with my xml file.
It is the result of a rest call and I only need to pick a few elements values (content).
Everything seems to be working fine, the function "findNodeName()" finds my element and picks its contents.
But what I want is to return current node (cur_node) back to it's caller for later processing.
I know I'm doing something wrong here, but can't get my head around it.
Why is xmlNodePtr NULL when it comes back to the calling function?
xmlNodePtr findNodeName(xmlNodePtr a_node, char **findIt)     
{
xmlNodePtr cur_node = a_node;   // a_node is the root node, picked upl earlier.
char *key = *findIt;        // Key is what I'm looking for
xmlChar *result = NULL;     
xmlNode *tmpNode = NULL;    
  
if (a_node == NULL) {
    printf("Empty document\n");
    return(NULL);
}
  
while (cur_node) {
    //printf("cur_node->name = %s, type = %d\n", cur_node->name, cur_node->type);
    if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur_node->name, (const xmlChar *) key ))) {
              
      printf("Node is: %s\n", cur_node->name);  // Work fine
      //tmpNode = xmlCopyNode(cur_node, 1);     // Test
      //printf("tmpNode: %s\n", cur_node->name);    // Also works fine
      result = xmlNodeGetContent(cur_node->children);   
      printf("Result: %s, ptr = %p\n", (char*)result, (void*)&result); // No problem here    either, got value (which is "true")
      if (cur_node != NULL) {
        return(cur_node);   // It's not NULL here
      }
    }    
    
    cur_node = cur_node->next;
}

for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next) {
    if ((cur_node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE)) {
      findNodeName(cur_node->children, findIt);
    }
}

return (NULL);
}


Calling function
int parseDocument(xmlstring *s)
{
  xmlDoc *doc;
  xmlChar *key;
  xmlNodePtr current;
  xmlNodePtr found;
  xmlChar *value;

......
......

printf("Where are we: %s\n", current->name);

char *searchNode = "IndividinformationGrunduppgifter";  // The node I'm looking for

while (current != NULL) {
if (current->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
    found = findNodeName(current, &searchNode);
    if (found != NULL) {
        // **Here is my problem, function findNodeName return's a NULL xmlNodePtr**
        // Always NULL here, 
        key = getSekretessValue(found);
            printf("Key: %s\n", key);
    } else {
        printf("found = NULL\n");
    }                 
      current = current->next;
}
}

I have tried with different forms of pointers and copy node with xmlCopyNode. All with same result, well same and same? I don't get my value.

Thank you, I need to improve my english.
